# What does the class LocationSettingsStates do when receiving location requests?

Tags: java, android, google-api, location

In the docs [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsApi#public-method-summary) I'm following how to receive location requests and two unusual things I noticed are in these two blocks of code:

```
result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
     @Override
     public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
         final Status status = result.getStatus();
         final LocationSettingsStates = result.getLocationSettingsStates(); //<--This line I don't understand
         switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
             case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                 // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                 // requests here.
                 ...
                 break;
             case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                 // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                 // a dialog.
                 try {
                     // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                     // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                     status.startResolutionForResult(
                         OuterClass.this,
                         REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                 } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                     // Ignore the error.
                 }
                 break;
             case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                 // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                 // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                 ...
                 break;
         }
     }
 });
```

And in the second block:

```
@Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     final LocationSettingsStates states = LocationSettingsStates.fromIntent(intent);  //<--And this line
     switch (requestCode) {
         case REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS:
             switch (resultCode) {
                 case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                     // All required changes were successfully made
                     ...
                     break;
                 case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                     // The user was asked to change settings, but chose not to
                     ...
                     break;
                 default:
                     break;
             }
             break;
     }
 }
```

I've added some arrows pointing to the lines I don't understand. In particular, these two:

`final LocationSettingsStates = result.getLocationSettingsStates();`

`final LocationSettingsStates states = LocationSettingsStates.fromIntent(intent);`

The first line is something I haven't seen before. How is this valid, assigning a value to a data type? Then that class is no longer used anywhere else in that block of code, so what's the purpose of the assignment?

In the other line, now it's assigning a value to an instance called `states` of that data type but that instance is not used anywhere else in `onActivityResult()`.

So what is going on here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The first line is definitely a typo; it should be something like:

```
final LocationSettingsStates states = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
```

And yeah, it isn't used in either place, which is weird, but you can call [things](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationSettingsStates) like `isBleUsable()` on it to determine what exactly is present and usable right now. In the latter case, it's what's usable after the attempted resolution.